# Custom Paging Panel DevExpress Reactive

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, devexpress, devextreme

I need to customize my Paging Panel this way:

1. instead of select Rows per page I need to render all sizes as buttons;
2. I don't need to render the numbers of rows are shown;
3. perhaps I need to customize buttons `< >` ;

As I understand, I need create my own Plugin, this is what I tried:

```
const CustomPagingPanel = ({ pageSizes }) => {
  const dep = [
    { name: 'PagingState' },
    { name: 'CustomPaging' },
  ]

  return (
    <Plugin 
      name="CustomPagingPanel"
      dependencies={dep}
    >
      <Template name="paging" >
        <TemplatePlaceholder />
        <div>Hi, I'm Custom Paginng Panel</div>
      </Template>
    </Plugin>
  )
}
```

And I added this plugin after PagingPanel in the Grid component, but it doesn't render anywhere.
What am I going wrong? How to get all states from PagingState and render my component instead of PagingPanel?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you override the containerComponent property of the PagingPanel plugin. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-moser-dcb8e?file=/paging-panel/pager.jsx:0-1432).